# A web-proxy between internet and smart-phone browser

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, proxy, web, wireless

I've already created an ad-hoc network connection between my Win-7 Laptop and Samsung smart-phone (Bada OS 2.0) through wifi. I've also checked the connectivity by veryifying the ip-addresses and pinging my smart-phone from the Laptop.

Now, I want to write a proxy-server that sits on my Win-7, accepts HTTP requests from smart-phone on port 8080, retrieves the webpage from internet, and passes it back to the smart-phone. The idea is twofold: to access internet on my smart-phone, and learn network programming with respect to mobile devices. I've written the following c-sharp code which implements the TCPListener to receive requests and send back the responses, which is happenning perfectly fine:

```
        private void listen()
    {
        try
        {
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Socket client= listener.AcceptSocket();
                ProcessClient(client);
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
        {
            WriteLog("Error occured: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ProcessClient(Socket client)
    {
        //extract client data
        byte[] bytes=new byte[1024];
        int size = client.Receive(bytes, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);

        string clientmessage = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

        if (size == 0)
            return;

        int index1  = clientmessage.IndexOf(@" ");
        int index2 = clientmessage.IndexOf(@" ", index1 + 1);
        if (index1 == -1 || index2 == -1)
        {
            throw( new Exception());
        }

        //extract client url
        string part1 = clientmessage.Substring(index1 + 1, index2 - index1);
        int index3 = part1.IndexOf(@"/", index1 + 8);
        int index4 = part1.IndexOf(@" ", index1 + 8);
        int index5 = index4 - index3;
        string sURL= part1.Substring(index1 + 4, part1.Length - index5 - 8);

        //send request to web server
        IPHostEntry serverHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(sURL);
        string[] aliases = serverHost.Aliases;
        IPAddress[] addresses = serverHost.AddressList;
        IPEndPoint serverEP = new IPEndPoint(addresses[0], 80);
        Socket server = new Socket((addresses[0].AddressFamily), SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server.Connect(serverEP);

        //server.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        byte[] sendbytes = new byte[1024];
        size = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientmessage, 0, clientmessage.Length, sendbytes, 0);
        server.Send(sendbytes, sendbytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        //server.Send(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientmessage), System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(clientmessage), SocketFlags.None);

        //read response from web server
        byte[] rbytes = new byte[4096];
        string strPage = "";
        size = 1;
        while (size > 0)
        {
            size = server.Receive(rbytes, rbytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                strPage += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rbytes,0,size);
        }
        server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        server.Close();

        //send the page back to the client
        //bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPage);
        bytes = new byte[strPage.Length+1];
        size = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPage,0,strPage.Length,bytes,0);
        client.Send(bytes, size, SocketFlags.None);
    }
```

The above code fetches the request from the client (smart-phone browser), fetches the request headers part and passes it to the web-server, and relays the response back to the smart-phone through the same client socket. This is happening alright. What goes wrong is that the web-server is sending a response of "Bad Request - Status code 400". I'm surprised this is happening as all I'm doing is relaying the requests back and forth between two end-points. Could you share some light on this? Here are the request headers that are sent and response headers received that I got by fetching the variables clientmessage and strPage respectively:

**Request:**

```
GET http://prahlad-tosh/welcome.png HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: prahlad-tosh
Accept: text/html, application/xml, image/vnd.wap.wbmp, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/bmp, application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml, application/xhtml+xml, application/vnd.wap.multipart.mixed, multipart/mixed, application/vnd.oma.dd+xml, text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor, application/java-archive, application/vnd.youtube, */*
Accept-Language: en
X-Wap-Proxy-Cookie: none
Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=1.0,iso-8859-1;q=0.6
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (SAMSUNG; SAMSUNG-GT-S5380K/S5380KDDKK6; U; Bada/2.0; en-us) AppleWebKit/534.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Dolfin/3.0 Mobile HVGA SMM-MMS/1.2.0 OPN-B
Referer: `http://prahlad-tosh/`
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Tue, 19 Jun 2012 14:10:14 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 326
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/htm/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
I think the problem can possibly be the server.
How about using Apache or connecting to google.com instead?

Side-note: I don't think you need the part `http://prahlad-tosh` in the GET request, just `/welcome.png` is fine.

Comment: But this is the exact header that the smart-phone browser is sending. Do you think the browser is sending incorrect headers? The browser software is Samsung Dolphin Browser v3.0

Comment: I think the problem can probably be the server, so try to request google.com

Comment: www.google.co.in sends this response, but nothing is displayed in the browser window: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 19 Jun 2012 15:59:04 GMT
Server: gws
Cache-Control: private
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

2d56
?

Comment: how about using a desktop browser? i can't see your added response clearly, can you edit your question and add it there?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Alvin. I found out what was wrong. Since the response I received from web-server was in chunks, I relayed the bytes back to client as soon as they were received, instead of first converting to string, strPage. Thats what solved the issue. Posting the new modified code soon. Also, a desktop browser is no use, as my browser is residing on a Samsung smart-phone where no IE or Firefox could be installed!!